# Blender > Unity - Exported with weird rotation

Tags: export, unity

By Default, blender exports to unity with -90 rotation on X
Using blender 3.0

here what i tried:

tick experimental "apply transform" > WORKS

z Forward Y up > DOES NOT WORK (multiple online post mention this, idk why it doesn't work)
randomly going x forward y up doesn't do anything else well
these options seem absolutely pointless)

https://github.com/EdyJ/blender-to-unity-fbx-exporter > DOES NOT WORK, addon doesn't show up

is there a proper way to do this other than using the apply transform? i heard it doesn't work will with complex meshes/systems.

Answer (score 1):

First off: The process of exporting from Blender to Unity is a huge mess, and you're doing great. Hang in there!

The real answer:

Even though it says "experimental" (or has the little ! icon, depending on your version), "experimental apply transform" has been around for a long time and will probably stick around for a long time too. So, it's reasonably safe to depend on it for now.

Applying scale/rotation/location can cause headaches sometimes, but it's certainly an important thing to research and try! (Just be sure to back up your project before making any kind of big change.)

For future projects, I recommend applying scale/rotation/location as early as possible, to make things easier as you go. For example, apply them to each object before parenting them to each other, especially with characters and armatures.

Edit: I may expand my answer later if you share other details of your project!